# Linux Kernel - Integer to ASCII

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I need to convert an integer to it's ASCII representation from within the Linux Kernel. How can I do this? I can't find any built-in conversion methods. Are there any already in the kernel or do I need to add my own?

Comment: I'm curious - what are you going to do with the ASCII rep inside the kernel?

Comment: It concerns me that someone working with kernel code would be asking this...

Comment: @Justin I suppose one has to start _somewhere_

Comment: Add me to the concerned list as well.

Comment: @Adriano Varoli Piazza - Yep, you nailed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel does offer `snprintf()`, would that suit your need? I'm also curious what you are doing with the ASCII representation of an integer within the kernel.

It's **very** likely that you just want `printk()`.

Comment: Yes, I was headed down the wrong path on this guys. Thanks for all the help. I realized I just wanted printk. First dive into kernel programming. Thanks!